# Why we can't assign to static parametrized array VBA?

Tags: vba

Why we can't assign values from range into static array :

```
Sub test()
'error occours
Dim a(1 to 10) as Double
'also don't work :
'Dim a(1 To 10, t To 1) as Double
a = Range("A1:A10")

End Sub
```

Comment: `a = Range("A1:A10")` doesn't return a single dimension array...

Comment: You could however write a function that accepts a range object and an array object `ByRef` and reads the range into the array. it could even be expanded into 2d arrays. This isn't common though because it is usually easier to learn how to work with the range object. `For each c in Range("A1:A10")` where `c` is a range will traverse every cell for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the array has already been allocated, regardless of how many dimensions you use.

```
Dim x(1 to 10, 1 to 1) As Variant '// You've allocated the array
x = Range("A1:A10").Value         '// Can't allocate to an already allocated array
```

You can declare an array of type `Variant` without allocating it and use that instead:

```
Dim x() As Variant        '// Array is NOT allocated
x = Range("A1:A10")       '// x = Array sized 1 to 10, 1 to 1
```

Assigning a range directly to an array in this way will always return a type `Variant/Variant` and so the receiving array must be of type `Variant` also.

---

You could create a UDF to do this for you, but it kind of defies the point of assigning directly from range:

```
Sub SO()
    Dim a As Variant
    a = RangeToArray(Range("A1:A10"))
End Sub


Function RangeToArray(rng As Range) As Variant
ReDim x(1 To rng.Rows.count, 1 To rng.Columns.count) As Variant
Dim r As Long, c As Long

For r = 1 To rng.Rows.count
    For c = 1 To rng.Columns.count
        x(r, c) = rng.Cells(r, c)
    Next c
Next r

RangeToArray = x

End Function
```